# Swap value in object array where other key value matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

**Overview:**

1. Object array that needs to have a value swapped from one of the objects to another object and vice versa.

- In this case the "position" key.

2. It will only perform the swap between the objects when a different value for a different key matched.

- In this case the "ID" key.

I thought I would post this question/answer to help people out who need this kind of function as I personally could not find it online.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Function:**

```
//This will change the inputted object array no need for return
export function Object_array_swap_other_object_values_based_on_other_object_value(
    object_array,   //this is the object array that the swap is being performed on
    change_key,   //This is the key for which will have the changed value
    Change_value_1,   // this is what the object with the matching locating_value_1 will change to
    Change_value_2,   // this is what the object with the matching locating_value_2 will change to
    locating_key,   //what key do you want to match
    locating_value_1,   //what value do you want that locating key to be for the first change
    locating_value_2   //what value do you want that locating key to be for the second change
) {
    object_array.map(data => {
        if (data[locating_key] == locating_value_1) {
            data[change_key] = Change_value_1
        } else if (data[locating_key] == locating_value_2) {
            data[change_key] = Change_value_2
        }
    })
}
```

---

**How to call function:**

```
object_and_array_helpers.Object_array_swap_other_object_values_based_on_other_object_value(lists,
      "position",
      desitnation_postion,
      origin_postion,
      "id",
      id_of_origin,
      id_of_destination
    )
```

This is what I currently use. However I'm sure this could be refractured.

If you have a better way to do this. Please show me :)

Comment: If there is a better way to structure my answer please let me know before downvoting. I am new to this :)